# How to refresh full screen and reload all 3 components in react-native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, software-design

I have an app which has 3 components that has data which come from API and all component data come from API. All components are called into a single screen. How can I apply pull to refresh on that single page?

I have done all expected terms but didn't find a solution.

Comment: At least provide some code snippets for us to be able to help

Comment: Please post what you tried and what went wrong and add some code and refer [how to add minimal reproducable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
```

> use RefreshControll that is the property of Scroll View
>
> here is the link that shows the example of RefreshControll and you can update the component's data using call api in onRefresh function.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol